# Telnet control character behaviour in CentOS vs Windows

Tags: telnet

I have been working with an old GSM gateway, the documentation shows me how to connect to the device via telnet to send SMS messages. My plan was to write an expect script on my CentOS server which would be able to send simple alert messages out when required.

When I tested this I connected to the PorTECH device using Windows telnet client, I had to enter the following commands:

```
module1
#The following command tells the device to echo back received commands to the telnet client
ate1

at+cmgf=1

at+cmgs="07XXXXXXXXX"

> Message to be sent
```

<kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>

At any point after selecting module1 you can press ctrl-x to release module1, this works fine.

<kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> is used here to send the message you have typed in.

I wrote an expect script to handle this series of events, but when it came to sending the <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> message (I used \032 and this displays ^Z in the terminal window when I run the script) nothing happened.

I was slightly baffled so I loaded up telnet in CentOS and went through the steps myself. I noticed that when I pressed <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> to release the module I had to have a carriage return for it to observe the command, so I tried adding that to my script (this didn't help). I also tried to run all of the commands mentioned above to send the SMS message, when it came to the part where I press <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> to send the message after inputting it, even if I follow the <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> input with a carriage return it was not observed.

I also tried running telnet with the -8 flag (I couldn't get past the login prompt) and the -7 flag which allowed me to login, but didn't overcome the issue with the <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> input at the end.

I also tried loading telnet, running "toggle localchars" and then trying to go through the steps which gave me the same result with <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>.

I have also seen a post suggesting to try "toggle options" and "toggle termdata" which can help diagnose the issue, but I am not sure what I am looking at, when I have these options set, the following comes out after I press <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>:

```
^ZSENT IAC SUSP
SENT DO TIMING MARK
```

I am not sure what this would mean, or how to check how it differs from Windows telnet operation. Can anyone advise why this input would have a different effect from pressing <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> in a Windows telnet session?

EDIT

From what I can tell, the [Microsoft telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/32866) program sends the same octal values to the telnet server as the [CentOS telnet](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html) program, so I really don't understand why pressing <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> works in Windows telnet, but doesn't work in CentOS telnet... from the advice of Zathrus in the #centos irc channel I also tried sending a <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> before my <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> (in both the script and simple telnet), and that didn't help either...

FURTHER EDIT

I have been doing some digging on this today, I ran Wireshark on my Windows machine and found that Windows sends a packet with "Data: \032" as expected, but when I capture the traffic with tcpdump of the telnet session on my CentOS machine it sends "Suspend Current Process" along with "Do Timing Mark".

Running the script I have written instead of manually connecting to telnet seems to send the same info, regardless of the fact I am sending the literal \032 expression it gets translated as "Suspend Current Process", in the same packet I also get the \r\n characters sent at the end of my expect.

Just for clarity, here is the script I have been using to send the messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Test script for SMS sends automatically via expect & telnet

#Set a sensible timeout

set timeout 20

#Our target device

set target 10.0.0.114

#set username and password info for SMS sending

set user voip
set pword 1234



#spawn the telnet session

spawn telnet $target

#Set up the expects fo the login process

expect "username:"

send "$user\n"

expect "password:"

send "$pword\n"


#I've only put a SIM in module1 so far

expect "]"

#check state1 for free, make sure it isn't in use already, exit if returns none

send "state1\n"

expect {
  "free" { send "module1\n" }
  "none" { send "logout\n" }
}

expect "got!! press 'ctrl-x' to release module 1." { send "ate1\n" }

expect "0" { send "at+cmgf=1\n" }

expect "0" { send "at+cmgs=\"07XXXXXXXXX\"\ntesting\032\015\012\n" }

#this should be the ctrl-z input as per http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html
#send "\032"

interact
```

I have also tried running a capture after going in to telnet and submitting the toggle localchars command before opening the connection to the GSM gateway, this capture also shows that the data sent over is "Suspend Current Process" followed by "Do Timing Mark"

Is there anything else I can do to send the literal \032 expression and not have it interpreted?

FURTHER EDIT:

Here are the captured packets from the Windows and Linux Telnet sessions

This is the hex captured for the Windows telnet session, the packet is shown in Wireshark as "Data: \032"

```
0000   00 03 7e 00 44 4f 30 85 a9 0e a6 52 08 00 45 00  ..~.DO0....R..E.
0010   00 29 3d 0b 40 00 80 06 b1 32 0a 00 f8 1f 0a 00  .)=.@....2......
0020   00 72 10 02 00 17 cf 41 a8 01 b0 3e 52 22 50 18  .r.....A...>R"P.
0030   f9 1d 06 5f 00 00 1a                             ..._...
```

This is the hex captured for the Linux telnet session, which shows in Wireshark as "Suspend Current Process" then "Do Timing Mark" :

```
0000   00 03 7e 00 44 4f 00 16 35 37 74 22 08 00 45 10  ..~.DO..57t"..E.
0010   00 2d 08 43 40 00 40 06 13 c6 0a 00 0a 41 0a 00  .-.C@.@......A..
0020   00 72 b1 46 00 17 b8 b3 01 36 a9 22 f2 7e 50 18  .r.F.....6.".~P.
0030   39 08 1e d2 00 00 ff ed ff fd 06                 9..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't have enough rep to comment*

Are you aware, that line-endings in (escapes are octal)

- Windows are CR+LF (\015\012)
- Linux is only  LF (\012)

the additional <kbd>RETURN</kbd> you have to enter, after <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd>, may be necessary after each executed command?

If it is like this, the gateway would encounter a concatenation of all sent strings, trying to parse them, inappropriately, as a single command (from your CentOS [hence Linux] machine)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have updated my question, the ate1 command will set the device to echo everything back to the telnet session so you know when something has been sent to it. I can provide inputs/responses if that would help. I noticed that when I hit ctrl-x or ctrl-z in the windows telnet it accepts it straight away and doesn't need a return. But in Linux it needed a return to send it to the telnet server. I will try adding those octals to my script though and see if it helps.

Comment: @Rumbles ofc, providing **full** in / and output (each distinguishably labeled) helps to debug the problem!

If possible, try to switch terminals into raw mode (so the control characters are automatically displayed)

Comment: @Rumbles the next step (If sth like RAW mode is not possible):
try to intercept the full traffic.

Linux: use piping with tee, i.e.
Windows: unfortunately, only sth full blown, like wireshark comes to my mind.

Comment: Hi @Florian, I'm not sure how I would go about setting the terminal to raw mode, but I have done some packet captures this afternoon. I've updated my question with further information. It seems that when I send the requests from telnet in CentOS the \032 octal is getting translated in to "Suspend Current Process" followed by "Do Timing Mark" regardless of whether I run toggle localchars beforehand or run it as a script sending the \032 as the control character. Any ideas why would be appreciated!

Comment: @Rumbles Unfortunately, this is where my telnet 'knowledge' stops. The last thing I can think of:  Try sending hex chars, instead of octal. (\032 == \x1A) and see, whether this makes a difference. (**also**: try different [telnet options](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42383/telnet-send-ctrl-c)-- At least you spot the distinct behavior of both telnet clients - hope you can track that down!!